# random whitespace when echoing HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, echo, whitespace

**Thanks so much to everyone who commented and answered this, The problem was missing a double quote from a div higher up on the page! Embarrassing, but again thanks for your efforts! for the record, my problem was that higher up on the page, there was a div like this:  directly before I inserted my dynamic div.**

I have a pretty simple problem, but I haven't been able to dig up any info on why it's happening.

basically I'm using php to echo quite a bit of html, about 6 divs. one div in particular always displays wrong when viewed on the browser. I'm using notepad++ encoding UTF-8 without BOM. here is an example:

in my index.php, I write:

```
<? echo '<div class="DivButton">Logout</div>'; ?>
```

all I see is the text 'Logout' without CSS. when I view the code in a browser it looks like this:

```
<div class=" divbutton">Logout</div>
```

Another clue is that often there are 1 or 2 lines before the class, for example in the browser:

```
   <div style="background:#000; left:0px;">Welcome to your website</div><div style="


divbutton">Logout</div>
```

and ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: Having a space inside the `class` attribute won't have an effect on the output at all. The content will be formatted according to the class name mentioned in the `class` attribute.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right piece of code? Maybe it's output somewhere else? Does it change when you change the suspected line of code? Does it help to just write the HTML outside `<?php ?>`, without `echo`ing it through PHP?

Comment: To confirm, is it also converting uppercase to lowercase? DivButton to divbutton?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there is no way from the code provided that whitespace can be generated unless you put it there without intention, HTML ignores white spaces anyway so there shouldn't really be such an issue. The case on the code you provided and the output do not match either? Are these actual snippets or just from what you have wrote here.

```
<div class="divbutton"><? echo 'Logout'; ?></div>
```

Try less echo, keep it simple so you can see that you are just echoing the 'Logout', I assume you will want this to be dynamic Login / Logout depending on whether there is a session.

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone who commented and answered this, The problem was missing a double quote from a div higher up on the page! Embarrassing, but again thanks for your efforts!

for the record, my problem was that higher up on the page, there was a div like this: <div style="></div> directly before I inserted my dynamic div. The real problem was coding way past 2am, haha